# Crystal Reports - Report Header has a blank space at the bottom

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report where the Report Header I have filling the whole first page with charts and sub reports. The rest continues on the second page.

Problem I am having is that the report header does not fill the whole page when running the report. It looks fine on the design view.

But when I run the report there is a space at the bottom of the report header. But if I make the report header height any larger it extends onto the second page. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[Bottom of Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xF45.png)

[Bottom of Live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKfkL.png)

[Second Page of Live](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lctke.png)

Comment: May you post a snapshot of the design and the report?

Comment: Are you wanting to fill the space at the bottom with the content from the header, or are you looking for a way to ensure the content after the header always begins on the next page and doesn't attempt to fill the space below the header?

Comment: I've added images. Please let me know if they help at all.

Comment: You need to `check next page after for Report Header`

Comment: I'm sorry. That didn't work.